# NodeJs Primus failOver

Tags: node.js, primus

I have one app that uses `primus` to connect using websockets.

I am in pursuit of making it redundant so the goal is that the client is connected to the websocket on node `X` and I have node `Y` on the server as the slave. How can I shutdown node `X` and without user notice it, connect his websocket to node `Y`?

I mean, suppose there is something on the backend processing. Meanwhile the client disconnects from node `X` and connects to node `Y`. I must have some logic to know that, that specific spark is from that client and then, when the processing end, I can send the reply to the client.

I have one MongoDb instance that will share data between the nodes, but I don´t know what data. I tried to save the spark, but I can´t since it has object methods.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No load balancer in the mix? [node-proxywrap](https://github.com/daguej/node-proxywrap) came to mind.